# some confuse about elf.h

Tags: c, compiler-construction, elf

1. Does elf.h have anything to do with compiler?
2. I'm a little confuse about the elf.h. I know the elf.h's most use case is when parse a ELF file. But I can still parse a ELF file byte by byte even don't use elf.h at all, right？ Although I know it' a little ugly.
3. Does all the ELF file follow the same format(firstly ELF header, then sections, section table, etc.)?

Comment: 1) ELF doesn't have anything to do with the compiler itself, but compilers must output binaries in a File Format that can be linked/loaded/executed by the operating system. ELF is such a file format, which is common for Linux systems. Also see PE for Windows, or MachO for MacOS. 2) You can certainly parse an ELF file *byte by byte* (not char by char, although space-wise they are generally the same). Building your own ELF parser can be a great exercise to better understand File Formats.

Comment: thanks for the answer @h0r53. another questions:
1. Can I say elf.h is not necessary needed in programming?
2. Does all the ELF file follow the same format(firstly ELF header, then sections, section table, etc.)?

Comment: 1) I don't fully understand the question. As a programmer you may not need to be concerned with `elf.h`, unless you are trying to make a compiler that outputs binaries in the ELF format. Compilers/assemblers generate executables in a target File Format, automatically if not specified. 2) Yes, ELF is a standard format, else loaders would have a difficult (or near impossible) time properly loading sections and executing programs.

Comment: ELF is a standard format, and the ELF header will always be the first thing in the file, but you cannot count on the tables, sections, etc. appearing in any particular order.  You have to find them by following pointers from the file header.

Comment: Please, add new informations and sub-issues by [edit]ing the question. And please write an answer if you have an answer. Comments are not for answers and extending questions.

Comment: @thebusybee Please don't second-guess commenters about whether they think they have the ability and time to write a complete answer to a question.

Comment: @h0r53  "I don't fully understand the question. As a programmer you may not need to be concerned with elf.h... "   ===  I'm working on writing a processor SystemC model which will execute C code, so I need write a parser to parse a ELF file, then let my model to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

1. `elf.h` is a header file that defines the format of ELF executable binary files, including executables, relocatable object files, core files, and shared libraries. ELF doesn't have anything to do with the compiler itself, but compilers must output binaries in a File Format that can be linked/loaded/executed by the operating system. Therefore, most compilers generating binaries in the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) include `elf.h` and use it to generate ELF binaries (otherwise the results may be non-standard). For example, GCC includes `elf.h` for these reasons.
2. The purpose of `elf.h` is to well-define the ELF format such that ELF binaries can be deterministically generated and parsed. You can absolutely create your own ELF parser, and it can be a great way to learn more about ELF.
3. Since ELF is a standard format it is well-defined. In other words, yes ELF binaries should follow the same overall structure, although the contents will clearly differ. It may be helpful to think of ELF as a binary wrapper that encapsulates sections of your code so that programs can be linked/loaded/executed consistently. If such a standard did not exist, it would be very difficult (or near impossible) for a loader to run binaries as we do today. Dynamically linking would pretty much be impossible.

Comment: >> " For example, GCC includes elf.h for these reasons. "
if GCC include elf.h, does that mean elf.h have relationship with the compiler?

Comment: @road Compilers are not obligated to output binaries in the ELF format. Also, `elf.h` has application in various software, so it's not just a compiler library. Compilers aiming to produce binaries in a variety of file formats would do well to follow the format specifications though. I'm not really sure what you're asking. If it is, "is it common for `elf.h` to be used in a compiler?" - then yes.